# Understanding the solution of this probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Given the following data:

```
P(B) = 0.02
P(B|A) = 0.94
P(A|B) = P(A'|B') = x
```

Now we solve the following equation to get the `x`

$ P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A|B)P(B) + \boldsymbol{P(A|B')} P(B')} = \frac{0.02x}{0.02x + \boldsymbol{P(A|B')} 0.98}$

So I know that $\boldsymbol{P(A|B')}$ is supposed to be $(1-x)$ apparently, but how exactly is that derived?

Comment: Just rearrange the equation to have something like $P(A\vert B') = ...$

Comment: Because from the given, $P(A'\mid B')=x$.

Comment: @stange you need to solve the `x` with $P(A|B')$ being another unknown. Now I know that it should be $(1-x)$, but how exactly is that derived. In other words, given the law of total probability we can know that $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B')$. How do I exactly solve $P(A \cap B')$ in this case?

Comment: @peterwhy $P(A'|B') = 1-P(A|B')$ ? Is that a general rule?

Comment: Given $B'$, then $A$ and $A'$ are complements. Or the two events $A\cap B’$ and $A'\cap B'$ partition $B’$.

Comment: @peterwhy got it, understood. Thank you.